# Scrollbar overlaps reject dialog when reviewing suggested edits

Tags: bug, status-declined, review-queues, suggested-edits, design

When reviewing suggested edits, the scrollbar for the diff is shown floating over the "reject" dialog.

[image]

In case it is relevant, I am using Chrome on macOS Sierra.

**UPDATE**
Also seeing this issue with the Top Nav Bar in sticky mode.
Screenshot:

[image]

Was unsure whether to update this or make a new post. Please let me know.

Comment: Isn't this an experimental feature of Chrome? What version of Chrome?

Comment: Chrome version - 56.0.2924.87 (64-bit) I havent set any experimental features.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

[status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined)

As far as I know, this is [default](https://jsfiddle.net/jqkwzg69/) browser behaviour. At least on macOS (with enabled feature for showing scrollbars only when scrolling) Chrome - scrollbar is always on top, even on top of fixed element with higher z-index. It's definitely not bug on our side, I'm not even sure if it's actually a bug at all.

Although, there is some CSS hack to fix it: we'd need to add `-webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);` to scrollable element.

However I'd rather avoid adding hacks like that because it just makes our code slightly less readable and obvious for other developers working on it. And the problem we're trying to fix here is too small to make it worth doing that.